# Sizes for Responsive website Design

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport

i want to design a web site.but tell me what are the sizes i can use for responsive website design. 
that sizes must contain for mobile,tablets,pcs and other devices..

i want to use them in media queries.. :D

EX for Mobile:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {

    }
```

EX for Tablet:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {

    }
```

***Give me some resources that you have about responsive website design and about the sizes which i can use for responsive website design .. :D***

**like that i want to know what are the reals sizes for these devices that i can use. :D**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* #1- Desktops */
@media (min-width: 980px) { ... }

/* #2- Portrait tablet to landscape and netbooks */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* #3- Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* #4- Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

For actual device specifications, check out [**this link by CSS-tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)..

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full list of media breakpoints

```
@media all and (max-width: 1690px) { ...}
@media all and (max-width: 1280px) { ...}
@media all and (max-width: 980px) { ... }
@media all and (max-width: 736px) { ... }
@media all and (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Check out for more informations about responsive device sizes : [Medium](https://medium.com/@uiuxlab/the-most-used-responsive-breakpoints-in-2017-of-mine-9588e9bd3a8a)

I hope so it's will help.